# regular expression in mysql select query

Tags: mysql, regex

How can we use regular expressions in select queries? For example:-

```
select regex(column1, regular_expression) from table1
```

I found REGEXP being used in where clause but cannot find something for selects like above.

For example, phone_number column in database has (845) 545 5545, the select query should return 8455455545

Comment: `SELECT * from table1 WHERE column1 REGEXP 'regular_expression'`?

Comment: Could you give us an example of what are you trying to do?

Comment: To be very specific I have phone numbers in different formats in phone_number column but would like to select only numbers out of it.

For example:
phone_number column has (845) 545 5545, the select query should return 8455455545

Answer (score 1):

You need MySQL 8.0 for this:

```
mysql> select regexp_replace('(845) 545 5545', '[() ]', '') as phonenumber;
+-------------+
| phonenumber |
+-------------+
| 8455455545  |
+-------------+
```

Comment: And MariaDB 10.0.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex you can try replace

```
SELECT Replace(Replace(Replace(column1,')',''),'(',''),' ','') FROM table1
```